# Country-based Super User Access, and modifiying Django Auth

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to give super user access to users of a program I'm devving.

All the entities have a country id value, so i'm just lookign to hook up my user model to have a country ID

Looking at Django Auth, It should be nice and easy to add a super_user_country_id field.

However, how frowned upon is it to modify the core django classes?

Is there any easier way to go about this or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the recommended way is to create a `Profile` model and link it to the `User` model with a `OneToOneField` or a `ForeignKey` (depending on your requirements). Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile) on the topic.

The Django devs have repeatedly expressed their intent to make extending the `User` model more straightforward, but AFAIK, no concrete design has been proposed, yet.

Comment: Thanks! My boss and I are far more comfortable with an approach like this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a custom `UserProfile` would be one way to go about this. `UserProfile` can link to `Country` and you can prevent users based on their `UserProfile`. I found James Bennett's article on [extending the User model](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/) useful when I had a similar requirement.

It is generally not a good idea to patch `auth` (or other built in) classes. Custom patches can become a pain to maintain and keep up to date.